# How to correctly run 'rename-item' remotely?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have declared the following variables:

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\user1\folder1'
$fname = 'abc.txt'
$tmp_fname = 'abc1.txt'
```

Now, I am remotely trying to execute below command:

```
invoke-command -cn $mycomp -Credential $mycred -ScriptBlock {
param($fname, $tmp_fname)   
   rename-item $dir\$fname -NewName $dir\$tmp_fname
} -ArgumentList ($fname, $tmp_fname)
```

Upon executing the above command, I am getting below error:

```
+     invoke-command -cn $server -Credential $host_cred -ScriptBlock {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: You're calling `$dir` on your scriptblock, however that variable is never being passed. You also want to start avoiding the use of `(..)` on your argument list as well as when passing arguments to your functions.

Comment: Besides the issues Santi pointed out, you can also use the UNC path: `Rename-Item -Path "\\$mycomp\c$\$fname" . . . .`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala can you please let me know how the updated script would look like? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, here are some comments and suggestion.

1. You are not passing all the arguments, in your case is `$dir`
2. `$dir` is an alias for `$env:windir` so try to use another name.
3. In your example `$dir = 'C:\Users\user1\folder1'` , you reference a specific user folder on a remote computer, that might work but you better be mindful with that reference.
4. Although it might work, I would try to avoid symbols between variables like that `$dir\$fname` , a better way would be to include the backslash in the `$dir` and then combine both like so `$($dir+$fname)`

With all that said, here is what I think should work for you

```
$dPath = 'C:\Users\user1\folder1\'
$fname = 'abc.txt'
$tmp_fname = 'abc1.txt'

invoke-command -ComputerName $server -Credential $host_cred -ScriptBlock {
    param($fname, $tmp_fname)   
    rename-item -LiteralPath $($dPath + $fname) -NewName $($dPath + $tmp_fname)
} -ArgumentList $fname, $tmp_fname , $dPath
```